# AttributeError: module 'urllib.request' has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create article so i need to request the current user's information.

```
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=user).get()  
    instance = profile
```

It gives me this error while trying to do it:

```
File "C:\...app\views.py", line 41, in aRTİCLECreateView
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
AttributeError: module 'urllib.request' has no attribute 'user'
```

Comment: This is a class-based view?

Comment: It is CreateAPIView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a class based-view, you access the request object with `self.request` (since it is a member of the view instance).

By writing `request.user`, your IDE probably made an imp0ort from the `urllib`:

```
    user = User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=user).get()  
    instance = profile
```

That being said, obtain the user with the id of the user, does not make much sense, since `user` will be the same as `self.request.user`, except that you make an extra query to the database, you thus can simplify the above code to:

```
    user = self.request.user
    profile = instance = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
```

Note that you can only write these statements in *methods*, not at the class-level, since at that level, there is no `self`.

Comment: Now it gives me error tthat says self is not defined?

Comment: @UmarBeyoğlu: because likely you define that at the class-level. You need to define that in a method, as specified at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: I was confused what you were talking about but now the problem has solved. First i thought i have to create self function in models but i had to use a function that has defined self before like create(self, etc..). Thanks a lot!